# TYPO3 6.0: PHP_SCRIPT was removed. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

It was years ago when I last used TYPO3 intensively. So I don't remember much TYPO-Script. When I updated to 6.0, I found out, that this code is no longer working:

```
marks.CONTENT.30 = PHP_SCRIPT
marks.CONTENT.30.file = fileadmin/db/db.php
```

It simply inserted the html output of the db.php (which did some database requests and formed a customized html/css table out of it).

How can I fix this quickly? I've heard that PHP_SCRIPT was deprecated, and that there is another keyword (USER), but I don't know, how to use it. Remember: I'm really no TYPO-Script expert any more, so feel free to explain in detail. ;-)

Thanks!
Ingo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need a basic extension, which, as you mentioned, is simply **USER** or **USER_INT** content objects.

First one is cached within a page content, so, if you script outputs some **static or rarely changed info**, you should consider to choose **USER** type.

If you have **dynamic data, which changes frequently** (every new page load brings new output), then you'd rather take **USER_INT**, but be aware: USER_INT script is called every time your page loads, so you must optimize it as much, as possible.

I advise you to read [this basic info](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html) about usage of these two types.

So, at the end you need a PHP class, which name starts from 'user_' or 'tx_' with a *main()* method, which takes two params *$content* and *$conf*. These params will not be used by you, but FYI, $content may contain pre-processed content, and $conf contains any configuration data, needed for your script.

Inside of *main()* you create your HTML output and just return it (as string).

TS part will be following in case of **USER**:

```
includeLibs.something = fileadmin/db/db.php
marks.CONTENT.30 = USER
marks.CONTENT.30 {
  userFunc = user_db->main
}
```

For **USER_INT**:

```
marks.CONTENT.30 = USER_INT
marks.CONTENT.30 {
  includeLibs = fileadmin/db/db.php
  userFunc = user_db->main
}
```

**NOTE:** I've described dirty, but easy way for your case. Much better will be consider using [CONTENT](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) cObject, because it does exactly, what you need: fetches records from DB and outputs them on page in a way, that you like.